# Does Oracle database need to be restarted to use Rman?

Tags: oracle, rman

We have an Oracle database which uses Rman. The server hosting Rman repositories crashed.

We've put the Rman server back online, but do we need to bounce the Oracle database to get it to start using Rman again?

Answer (score 1):

Not for any reason I know of.

Once you're done installing and configuring RMAN (don't forget to create and register the recovery catalog), you should be good to go without restarting anything.